# Why am I getting "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'replace'" on string.replace()

Tags: python, string, floating-point

The line causing the error is

```
totalR = totalR + (float(string.replace(contri[0][5],",","")) + float(string.replace(contri[0][6],",","")))
```

contri[0][5] and [6] are strings that contain numbers formatted as 1,000.00.  I'm removing the commas before I cast the strings as floats in order to add them to totalR, which is a float.  (Created as totalR = 0.0)  I also tried using Decimal, but the error happened there too.  I did "import string".  The program fails with error:

```
File "mine.py", line 43, in fillDonorData
totalR = totalR + (float(string.replace(contri[0][5],",","")) + float(string.replace(contri[0][6],",","")))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: I have used '10,000' instead of 'contri[0][5]' and 'contri[0][6]' in your code and everything works fine. I am on Python 2.7. If you are trying this on python 3 you should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452108/how-to-use-string-replace-in-python-3-x)

Comment: I'm assuming you're on Python 3.x? If so, you should include that tag in your question. Also, you should paste the entire traceback, not just the error itself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Methods in the `string` module have been deprecated for years. You should call `replace` directly on your string, or `contri[6]`.

Comment: In 2.x, the [Deprecated string functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#deprecated-string-functions) still work despite being deprecated. In 3.x, most of them (including `replace`) no longer exist. However, there are still plenty of non-deprecated functions, constants, and classes in `string`.

Answer (score 5):

It is now on [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) on Python 3.

Looks like the same thing renamed, have the same signature and a docstring with the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

If you made changes to your module, just exit python shell and enter again and import your module again

Comment: `string` is a builtin module. But this is correct, you would have to reload if changes are made.