# How can JSON data with null value be converted to a dictionary

Tags: python

```
{
  "abc": null,
  "def": 9
}
```

I have JSON data which looks like this. If not for null (without quotes as a string), I could have used `ast` module's `literal_eval` to convert the above to a dictionary.

A dictionary in Python cannot have `null` as value but can have `"null"` as a value. How do I convert the above to a dictionary that Python recognizes?

Comment: Always use the [json module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) for parsing json.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You should use the built-in [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), which was designed explicitly for this task:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = '''
... {
...   "abc": null,
...   "def": 9
... }
... '''
>>> json.loads(data)
{'def': 9, 'abc': None}
>>> type(json.loads(data))
<class 'dict'>
>>>
```

By the way, you should use this method even if your JSON data contains no `null` values.  While it may work (sometimes), `ast.literal_eval` was designed to evaluate *Python* code that is represented as a string.  It is simply the wrong tool to work with JSON data.

Comment: hd1 - for some reason. iCodez comment showed up first. Sorry! so i had to mark it as the answer but thanks Good show!

Comment: @user2921139: If you really want to translate `null` to `"null"` rather than `None` as your question implies, you will need to do a bit of extra work. But I suspect that you don't want that.

Comment: No abarnert. I am good but curious - how would u do the null to "null"?

Comment: Is there any way to do null to  "null" ?

Comment: To replace you can surely use the string.replace() method, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9452122/11120444

Answer (score 35):

One solution is to use a variable that contains None.

```py
import json
null = None
data = { "test": null }
json.dumps(data)
```