# How to remove a comma in an output

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

```
def calculate_average():

mylist = []

for i in range (10):
    input = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
    mylist.append(integer)

avg = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)

aboveavg = ([x for x in numbers if x > average])

print("\nThe average is:", avg)
print("Numbers greater than average:")
print(str(aboveavg).strip('[]'))
```

I get an output for the very last line where it has a comma. For example

```
Numbers greater than average:
14, 15
```

Instead of:

```
14 15
```

How to go about fixing the code? Do I use join? (something I haven't learned about in class yet)

Comment: .replace will 'fix' your code vs .strip. duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452108/how-to-use-string-replace-in-python-3-x

Comment: Why exactly are you showing us all that code for building `aboveavg` (and not showing us input for it)? Should we care?

Answer (score 2):

You could use join, which concatenates a string before printing it:

```
print(' '.join(str(elt) for elt in aboveavg))
```

or a for loop where you print one element at a time on the same line:

```
for elt in aboveavg:
    print(str(elt), end=' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you should use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) in this case. It is the built-in way to achieve this:

```
print(' '.join(map(str, aboveavg)))
# or:
print(' '.join([str(x) for x in aboveavg]))
```

It is important to note that you can only join `str` objects. You will have to convert the elements of the iterable you want to join to `str`. You can use either [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) or a comprehension to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily

```
print(" ".join([str(x) for x in aboveavg]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Since the result is a list, you can create a string from a list by using join:

```
print (' '.join(map(str, your_list)))
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea why everybody's joining...

```
print(*aboveavg)
```

Comment: `join` is definitely the tool to know. It is more flexible, e.g you can further process the resulting str, whereas `print` just prints.