# PHP's str_replace in Python?

Tags: php, python

Is there anything similar in Python like PHP's str_replace function?

I am looking for something to do this:

```
string_world = str_replace('Place', "World", "Hello World!")
print (string_world)

Hello Peter!
```

Specifically something to replace my

```
str_replace('mp', ' ', $_GET['FML'])
```

Comment: http://www.php2python.com/wiki/function.str-replace/

Comment: [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452108/how-to-use-string-replace-in-python-3-x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing when you are printing "Hello Peter" You should write `string_world = str_replace("World", "Peter", "Hello World!")` Please check your question.

For String replace in Python, use something like this:

```
str = "Hello World"
print str.replace("World", "Peter") 
print str.replace("World", "Peter", 1) #Parameters: str.replace(find, replace, count)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.replace()` on string:

```
str = "Hello World!"
print str.replace("World", "Place")
```