# Converting time format , string to float

Tags: python, string, date, datetime, strftime

How can I convert a time string '15:04:23' (hours:minuts:seconds) into a float 150423, using python?
The following steps had been done yet:

Initially I have the time/date information in the format seconds since 01.01.2000. I converted this using the following function

```
 t_temp = datetime(2000,1,1)+timedelta(seconds = t)
```

Then I extracted the time

```
t_temp.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

... which gives me string

Comment: Why do you want a float `150423` for `"'15:04:23' "`? That does not make any sense. It just implies that you can perform math on that, e.g. calculate the difference between two times, but you can't. If you want the time as a numeric value, use a proper timestamp.

Comment: I need this to compare two different data set ;)

Comment: Do you mean that the dates in the _other_ data set are in this format, and you want to convert yours into the same format? Still, might make more sense to look at the code that produces those other float-dates and fix it.

Comment: that's not possible, because the other data set is produced by the European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts. I don't have access to their codes ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this

```
time = float(t_temp.replace(":",""))
```

this will remove the colons and typecast the string into float.Works in both python2 and python3

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int-in-python) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452108/how-to-use-string-replace-in-python-3-x) two useful links

Comment: Not my downvote, but this is probably the most cumbersome and inefficient way to remove those `:`... better just use `str.replace`, or just use a different format for `strftime` in the first place.

Comment: @tobias_k I tried to address what was asked in the question in an easily understandable way.
But you are right.
I will make the respective change.

Answer (score 1):

Just omit the colons and cast the result to a float:

```
float(t_temp.strftime("%H%M%S"))
```

I don’t know how much sense this really makes, but there you go.