# How to remove triple double-quotes around values in csv files?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql

I have a csv file. each value is quoted with `"""` quotes . I want to remove it for further processing

here is my csv file

```
Name,age,class,place
""""ishika""","""21""","""B"""","""Whitefield"""
"""anju""","""23""","""C""","""ITPL"""
```

I want the output as:

```
Name,age,class,place
ishika,21,B,Whitefield
anju,23,C,ITPL
```

I am getting csv form postgres table..

```
import psycopg2
import config as cfg
conn = cfg.DATABASE_CONNECT
cur = conn.cursor()
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tablename = "sf_paymentprofile_error_log"
query = "SELECT * from {} ".format(tablename)
outputquery = "COPY ({0}) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER".format(query)
with open(cfg.PG_EXTRACT_PATH+'sf_paymentprofile_error_log.csv', 'w') as f:
   cur.copy_expert(outputquery, data)


conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

I want the above output using python.Thanks.

Comment: in what data structure you're loading you data ? list , dataframe ?

Comment: i am converting this csv into "list"

Comment: Use `<string>.replace('"""', '')` to remove `"""` from string [How to use string.replace() in python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9452122)

Comment: doing replace i get the following error.                                                
    AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace'

Answer (score 0):

a way of doing it using pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv")


for i in df.columns :         
    df[i] = df[i].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace('"',''))

df.to_csv("output.csv",index=False)
```

if it is a list :

```
output = []
for row in your_data :  
    b = []
    for val in row : 
        b.append(val.replace('"',''))
    c.append(b) 

print(output)
```

Comment: i am getting csv from postgres table

Comment: there are various ways reading your table with pandas, df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from "table"',con=engine) , all that matters is your resulting dataframe on which you will have to do the preprocessing

Answer (score 0):

Remove them by treating them as quotes but `csv` only accepts one-char separator so:

```
import re
with open('data.csv') as f:
    # replace """ to single "
    data = (re.sub(r'"+', '"', line) for line in f.readlines())
    # now treat it as normal csv
    rd = csv.reader(data, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    # print 
    for row in rd:
        print(','.join(row))
```

Or if you find it's safe, do `re.sub('"', '', f.read())` for the whole file.

Comment: @ishika it's the same, use `lines = csv_str.split('\n')`. The csv content string cane be read by executing the query. Considering you are using postgres, you should already know the basic file & string operations though.

Answer (score 0):

Both [`pd.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and [`pd.str.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) will help, for example:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('"'))
```

Anyway, some of the rows of your csv have a `"` succession that *hides* some `,` separator, so if I apply strip function:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("my.csv")
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('"'))
print(df)

     Name age            class place
0  ishika  21  B"","Whitefield   NaN
1    anju  23                C  ITPL
```

The first workaround I've found implies a change of the `quotechar` param:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("my.csv", quotechar="'")
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('"'))
print(df)

     Name age class       place
0  ishika  21     B  Whitefield
1    anju  23     C        ITPL
```