# Is there a way to directly edit a certain text file line through the OS module? (Python 3.7)

Tags: python-3.x, function, file, operating-system

I am trying to make a game, where your score saves as a text file. The score (clicks) must always be on the second line and save per user. Every time a user saves, I would like the second line of the text file to be replaced with the new score.

I have tried using loads of things suggested on stack overflow, like the os.replace or os.resub, but none work.

```py
def save():
    global userlog
    global clicks
    score = open(directory + "/" + userlog + ".txt", "r+")
#### On this line, I want some code that will replace the second line in the text file listed above.
    for i in range(random.randint(2,5)):
        print("Saving")
        time.sleep(0.10)
        print("Saving.")
        time.sleep(0.10)
        print("Saving..")
        time.sleep(0.10)
        print("Saving...")
        time.sleep(0.10)
    print("\nGame Saved Sucessfully!")
```

I have not had anything work. Just getting some standard error messages.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Thanks :)

Comment: no, as far as I know. just had a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58078287/search-a-string-in-a-text-file-and-copy-and-paste-that-line-in-same-text-file). what you can do is load the text to a variable, edit the variable on save, write the variable back to the text file. not even needs `os`.

Comment: But I want to later on in the program read the 2nd line, and can't just keep adding scored on save. I need some code that will set the second line to (clicks) upon clicking save.

Comment: to clarify: I meant edit the variable if the 'save' operation is called. so your `save()` function must include: load logfile, edit loaded data, write data back to logfile (overwrite existing or create new).

Comment: by the way, `os.replace` renames a file, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) (scroll down a bit). a bit missleading I would say ;-)

Comment: Oh wow, that could actually be pretty useful :)

Comment: Could I use the script that you gave me to change passwords, usernames and more? That would be perfect!

Comment: In principle, yes. Although I would suggest not to save passwords in plain text. You could use e.g. `string.replace` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452108/how-to-use-string-replace-in-python-3-x)) and so on...

Answer (score 1):

an illustration of my comment - your save function could do something like

```py
# load previously logged information
with open(logfile, 'r') as fobj:
    log = fobj.readlines()

# replace line 2 with some new info
log[1] = 'some new info\n'

# overwrite existing logfile        
with open(logfile, 'w') as fobj:
    for line in log:
        fobj.write(line)
```

In principle you could also use `open()` in `r+` mode as you wrote in the question. That would require you to use `seek()` (see e.g. [here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/file/seek.html)) to get the file pointer to the position you want to write at - a more complicated option which I would not recommend.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much. Just to clarify, what does "fobj" mean? I am still a baby at python :p

You are not the hero we deserved. You are the hero we needed chief ;-;

Comment: @JJKenna: I use `fobj` as a short form for "file object" - that is what `open()` returns (see e.g. [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)). More on the `with` statement e.g. [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/with-statement-in-python/) - just a convenient way of having the garbage collection (`.close()` etc.) being done for you.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. This makes a lot of sense to me now. :)

Comment: I am getting this error, I do no think it is too major, and could be fixable. Could you please check to see what is wrong?
```python
line 19, in save
    log[1] = clicks
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

my current code is
```python
def save():
    global userlog
    global clicks
    with open(directory + "/" + userlog + ".txt", "r") as fobj:
        log = fobj.readlines()
        log[1] = clicks
    with open(directory + "/" + userlog + ".txt", "w") as fobj:
        for line in log:
            fobj.write(line)
```

Comment: @JJKenna your logfile does not seem to contain more than one line if you can't access `log` at index 1. print `log` for debugging, and if you write to the file, don't forget to add the new line `'\n'` - otherwise, `.readlines()` will not know where a line ends when the file is re-loaded.

Comment: In my script, you create 2 lines. Your username, and your score. I would like to edit line 2.

Comment: then the content of your logfile should look like 'username\n' in the first line and 'score\n' in the second line.

Comment: ```python
    log[1] = clicks
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```
I changed where it writes the score in the first place and added a \n, still getting this error.

```python
data.write("0\n")
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/CZmrC0Dv
here is my entire script if it can help you help me solve the issue :)

Comment: @JJKenna: sorry, had to go offline yesterday. I think the error you got was due to a missing newline as I noted above. the line `log[1] = clicks` should be something like `log[1] = str(clicks) + '\n'` or `log[1] = f"{clicks}\n"` in f-string notation. Besides the newline, note that clicks is an integer - to write it to a text file, you'll have to format it as string.

Comment: oh my god it works. you are amazing! thank you so much.

JJ.

Comment: @JJKenna: great, glad I could help!

Comment: how can i make my program read from the second line as an integer? i have printed the "clicks" when the program starts and all i get is "[]".

Comment: @JJKenna: if the line read from the file prints as "[]", it seems to me that the line did not contain anything. if read correctly, it should print as "5\n" (if the score was 5). you can then convert `line` to integer by `int(line)`. Also, in your linked code, I noted that `register_screen()` has a line `data = open(...`. If you don't use `with...`, make sure to add `data.close()` when you're done writing.

Comment: eek. i did something and it completely broke my code. cannot fix it :/

https://pastebin.com/vTi18XvV

Comment: @JJKenna: you're still on this? Your code sort-of runs with slight modifications like: remove `clicks = userlog.readlines(2)` You'll have to properly read the logfile here, you know how to do this by now ;-). second, don't use `import *` - explicitly say what you import like `from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label` - much more readable!