# How do i remove the adsense code in requests_html?

Tags: python, web-scraping, adsense, python-requests-html

I am using the `requests_html` library to scrape a website but i am getting at the same time the *adsense* from that website from that grabbed text. The example looks something like this:

> some text some text some text some text and then this:
>    ***(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});***
>
> some text some text some text after a line break and then this:
>    ***sas.cmd.push(function() {  sas.call("std", {  siteId: 301357, //  pageId: 1101926, // Page : Seneweb_AF/rg 
>   formatId: 49048, // Format : Pave 2 300x250  target: '' //
>   Ciblage  });  });***

Now how can i get rid of the italic-bold text above?

Answer (score 0):

If `requests_html` doesn't have a builtin mechanism for handling this, then a solution is to use pure python; this is what i found so far:

```
curated_article = article.text.split('\n')
curated_article = "\n".join(list(filter(lambda a: not a.startswith("&#"), curated_article)))
print(curated_article)
```

where `article` is the `html` for a scraped article

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are able to get hold of the text as a string before you need to remove the unwanted parts, you can search and replace.

If `(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});` is always the exact same string (including the same whitespace every time), then you can use `str.replace()`.
See [How to use string.replace() in python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452108/how-to-use-string-replace-in-python-3-x).

If the text is not the exact same thing every time--and I am guessing that at least the second example you showed is not the same every time--then you can use regular expressions. See [the python documentation of the `re` module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#module-re).
If you only use a few regular expressions in your program you can just call `re.sub`,
something like this:

```
sanitized_text = re.sub(regularexpression, '', original_text, flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
```

It may take some trial and error get get `pattern` to match every case that is like the second example.

You'll need `re.MULTILINE` if there are newlines inside the retrieved article, as there almost certainly will be, and `re.DOTALL` in order to make certain regex patterns work across line boundaries, which it appears the second example will require.

If you end up having to use several regular expressions you can compile them using `re.compile` before you start scraping:

```
pattern = re.compile(regularexpression, flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
```

Later, when you have text to remove pieces from, you can do the search and replace like this:

```
sanitized_text = pattern.sub('', original_text)
```