# Parsing csv rows in order to create a new column

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying create a new column in my tab-delimited text file using Python.

Currently each row looks like

```
"Mk 1:23" \t "text" \n
```

and I would like to change each of them to

```
"Mk" \t "1:23" \t "text" \n
```

Comment: replace the space character with the tab character. https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace

Comment: This question could be similar to this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452108/how-to-use-string-replace-in-python-3-x

Comment: @Oxymoron, your first solution was perfect. Just got rid of the first instance of space and replaced with "\t". Thanks for your help. Why don't you answer the question and I will let you have the rights to the answer.

Comment: It seems you would need to replace the space with `"\t"`.