# Strings: replacing a word in a string

Tags: python, string

Given the string “To dance or not to dance”, have the program replace all occurances of the word “dance” with “be”.

**My attempt but its having error**

```
    word = "To dance or not to dance"
    replaceWords = str_replace("dance","be", word)
    print (replaceWords)
```

Comment: use the string `replace` method https://stackoverflow.com/a/9452122/5180047

Answer (score 2):

```
new_word=word.replace("dance", "be")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can work.

```
word = word.replace("dance","be")
```