# how do I insert a question mark before every comma in a string python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

how do I insert a question mark before every comma in a string with python?
for example, the sting would be

```
string = 'the, quick, brown, fox, jumps, over, the lazy, dog'
print(string)
```

and the desired output would be

```
the?, quick?, brown?, fox?, jumps?, over?, the?, lazy?, dog
```

Comment: ```string.replace(",", "?,")```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use string.replace() in python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452108/how-to-use-string-replace-in-python-3-x)

Comment: `print(string)` — prints the string above. Can you share your code, so we could help you correct it?

Comment: @Sushanth shouldn't you write you answer in an actual answer box?

Comment: @NoahNoahNoah, taught it would get duplicated so ignored it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do this

```
string.replace(",", "?,")
print(string)
```

would output in:

```
'the?, quick?, brown?, fox?, jumps?, over?, the?, lazy?, dog'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string_list = string.split(", ")

new_list = []
for string in string_list:
    new_list.append(string + "?")
final_string = ", ".join(new_list)
```

Or this:
new_string = string.replace(", ", "?, ")