# String Replace 'Null' with Null in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to replace single quotes:

`input= "something='Null', someone=Null, somethingmore='realval'"`

desired output

`"something=Null, someone=Null , somethingmore='realval'"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use string.replace() in python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452108/how-to-use-string-replace-in-python-3-x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do

```
input.replace("'Null'", "Null")
```

but don't use input as a variable, since it is also the builtin input function.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the replace function:

```
input = "something='Null', someone=Null"
print(input)

output = input.replace("'Null'", "Null")
print(output)
```

The output:

```
something='Null', someone=Null
something=Null, someone=Null
```