# Strings replacement in Python by replacing numerical digits with characters

Tags: python

How to replace numerical with character set in the string without using numpy or pandas in python?

Example:

> Original String = A student has secured 90% of marks whose roll number
> is 2012684954
>
> Updated string  = A student has secured 90% of marks whose roll number
> is 201HKM4954

Comment: You could use the replace function

Comment: You could just the `str.replace` method and loop through all the replacements. Replacements can be defined in a dictionary as a key: value pair. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452108/how-to-use-string-replace-in-python-3-x

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use string.replace() in python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452108/how-to-use-string-replace-in-python-3-x)

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments you can use `replace` function and a dictionary to store the replacements:

```
string = 'A student has secured 90% of marks whose roll number is 2012684954'

replacements = {
    '268': 'HKM',
    '90': 'AA'
}

for rep in replacements:
    string = string.replace(rep, replacements[rep])

print(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the requirements, here is something you can use:

1. regular expressions ([re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub))
2. any of the built-in python string methods (like [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace))