# How to delete specific char and space in python

Tags: python, string, strip

I want to get 59,000 but I can't get what I want.

```
a='5M 9,000'
a.strip('M')
```

Comment: `a = a.replace("M ", "")`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use string.replace() in python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452108/how-to-use-string-replace-in-python-3-x)

Comment: Does the `M` stand for "million?"  If so, then do you want 5,009,000 as the output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex module's `sub()` function, this returns a string where all matching occurrences of the specified pattern are replaced by the replace string.

Note:- '\D' is used to match all decimals, i think you're trying to extract numbers from the string?

```
 import re
 a = '5M 9,000'
 a=re.sub(r'\D', '', a)#59000
 print(f'{int(a):,}')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
59,000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
a = '5M 9,000'
"".join(re.findall(r'\d+', a))

# 59000
```

or if want output with comma;

```
"".join([i for i in a if i.isnumeric() or i == ","])

# 59,000
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete a single char at a specified location

```py
a = '5M 9,000'
a = a[:c]+a[c+1:]
```

where c is the location of the char

For deleting multiple chars starting from a specified location

```py
a = '5M 9,000'
a = a[:c]+a[c+length:]
```

where length is the number of chars you want to remove starting from the location c

```py
a = '5M 9,000'
c = 3
a = a[:c]+a[c+1:]
```

a will be `'5M ,000'`

```py
a = '5M 9,000'
c = 3
length = 2
a = a[:c]+a[c+length:]
```

a will be `'5M 000'`

making it into 59,000

```py
a = '5M 9,000'
c = 1
length = 2
a = a[:c]+a[c+length:]
```

output
a is `'59,000'`

Comment: oneline `a = a[:1]+a[3:]`